# Understanding this simple movl opcode

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code, instruction-encoding

I'm starting to learn to read opcodes and I've found this:

```
89 75 95 movl %esi, var_6ch
```

where `var_6ch` is at `ebp-0x6c`

Which part of `89 75 95` indicates the 'address'  `ebp-0x6c`? I've found on internet that `89` is the code for movl, maybe 75 is for register esi? or maybe the 2 bytes encode these 2 informations.

Where can I find more about this and quick search these things?

Comment: Have you looked in the Intel manuals?

Comment: Read the Intel Software Development manuals.  What you are looking for is called the *modr/m byte* indicating operands and addressing modes and the *displacement byte* indicating the displacement.

Comment: @fuz: We already have [tag:machine-code] and [tag:machine-language] redundant tags, we probably don't need an [tag:instruction-encoding] tag as well.  Or it should be a synonym.  (I just proposed machine-language as a synonym of machine code: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-code/synonyms)

Comment: @PeterCordes I still think a separate tag has its merits just to gather the questions asking specifically about how the instruction encoding of various architectures works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo, it is "movl %esi, -0x6b(%ebp)".
0x95 is 0x100 - 0x6b; that is the binary encoding for -0x6b.

I found this out by making a simple file, y.s, and entering:

```
movl %esi, -0x6c(%ebp)
```

Compiling it for 32 bit (cc -m32). Then, with otool (macos, objdump if you are linux) dumping the text section : otool -t;  Then I added a few more lines:

```
movl %esi, -0x6b(%ebp)
movl %esi, -1(%ebp)
```

which yielded:

```
Contents of (__TEXT,__text) section
00000000    89 75 94 89 75 95 89 75 ff
```

making the content quite apparent.   Next try replacing %ebp with %esp, %eax, then %esi with %edi, %edx, etc...  Or read the manual.

Comment: Thanks; it looks like I forgot to run cc again after the last edit.  fixed.